# Perform two queries at the same time (reactive)

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I know it is asynchronous and therefore the values I want to save will be null (I checked). How can I fix this so that everything is saved correctly?

I want to save a Document and at the same time get that ID generated by MongoDB to save to another API.

```
public Mono<BankAccountDTO> save(BankAccountDTO bankAccount) {
    
    return mongoRepository.save(AppUtils.dtoToEntity(bankAccount))
        .doOnNext(d -> {
            
            CustomerRoleDTO cDto = new CustomerRoleDTO();
            cDto.setBankAccountid(d.getId());
            cDto.setClientId(bankAccount.getCustomerId());
            
            webClient.post()
                .uri("http://localhost:9292/api/v1/example")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .body(Mono.just(cDto), CustomerRoleDTO.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(CustomerRoleDTO.class);
            
        }).map(AppUtils::entityToDTO);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are breaking the chain by not handling the return from your wbClient call, so that reactor can't fulfill assembly time.

(i have not checked against a compiler, but something like this)

```
public Mono<BankAccountDTO> save(BankAccountDTO bankAccount) {
    return mongoRepository.save(AppUtils.dtoToEntity(bankAccount))
        .flatMap(d -> {
            
        CustomerRoleDTO cDto = new CustomerRoleDTO();
        cDto.setBankAccountid(d.getId());
        cDto.setClientId(bankAccount.getCustomerId());
            
        // you cant ignore the return
        return webClient.post()
                .uri("http://localhost:9292/api/v1/example")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .body(Mono.just(cDto), CustomerRoleDTO.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(CustomerRoleDTO.class)
                .thenReturn(d);
    });
}
```

here you can read more about `assembly time`.

[Assembly vs Subscription](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription)

Comment: Dont you think a better operator to use would be `zipWhen` ??

Comment: @Harry that is an opinion, He asked why it wasnt executed, i answered. I dont see why zipWhen would be a "better" solution, than maybe less lines, that doesn't mean "better". He didnt ask "what is the shortest amount of lines i can execute this with", or "what is the highest performing solution"

Answer (score -1):

Use `flatmap` instead of `doOnNext`